# Angular2-swiper ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have to implement ksachdeva/angular2-swiper in my ionic 3 application . it works good in the browser  (ionic serve). 
But when I try to build the application it throws this error :

```
[22:47:59]  ngc started ... 
[22:48:10]  typescript error 
            Unexpected value 'KSSwiperContainer in 
            /Users/--/Desktop/aws/node_modules/angular2-swiper/dist/ks-swiper.d.ts' imported by the module 
            'AppModule in /Users/--/Desktop/aws/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation. 

Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
    at /Users/---/Desktop/aws/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:237:55
    at step (/Users/--/Desktop/aws/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/--/Desktop/aws/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/--/Desktop/aws/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
[22:48:11]  copy finished in 12.74 s
```

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import {KSSwiperModule} from 'angular2-swiper';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      scrollAssist: true,
      platforms: {
          android: {
              scrollAssist: true
          }
      }
    }),
    KSSwiperModule,
    MomentModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
.......
```

And this is Home Page

```
import {KSSwiperContainer, KSSwiperSlide} from 'angular2-swiper';
export class HomePage {

  swipeOptions: any;
  days: any[];
  //dailyStats: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  overview: any;
  realTimeDaily: any;

  swiper: any;
  pi: number;
  maxWattPerHour: number;

  @ViewChild(KSSwiperContainer) swiperContainer: KSSwiperContainer;

......
```

Any help ? and Thanks :D

Comment: You have to add `KSSwiperContainer` to the `@NgModule` in `app.module.ts`

Comment: in the declaration ? because i already tried to add it to the ng imports but still the same issue

Comment: Yes in the `@ngModule` declaration

Comment: I did but still the same problem so i am currently using ngx angular swiper wrapper :D thanks for your help

Comment: ok, pleasure to help you.